# Oauth2: Spring Boot 2: Design: Distinct Auth Server and Resource Server - where to store all user information?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

1. My client app contains user registration page that will contain
   information like - email, country, address and some other
   demographic details related to the user - in addition to username
   and password. What is recommendation on to persist this information?
   Auth Server must only persist username and password and all other
   details should be persisted in the Resource Server? I need all the
   User information when I access protected endpoint in Resource
   Server. What if I create another Resource Server in addition to
   existing one - then I end up duplicating all the information again.
   So I am thinking I should store all the user details in Auth Server
   so as to have single source of truth about the user.
2. If all user details are in Auth Server, how do I make that user information
   available to every protected endpoint in the Resource Server? What
   changes I need to make in Auth Server and Resource Server to make
   this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question - it is a design question and the best option is to separate concerns

I would recommend handling it via claims and to keep central + product user data separated:
https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/

Happy to explore any follow on questions with you ..

Comment: Thanks @Gary Archer for the link to your article and it makes sense to me. I too will go with separating "central user data" and "product user data". If you have implemented your suggested design - was that using spring boot 2 and oauth 2 or something else? If yes, is it possible for you to share the sample code that encompasses above design or some part of it? Thanks again

Comment: Cool - this sample represents the logic I tend to use in its most simple form: https://github.com/authguidance-examples/authguidance.websample2/blob/master/api/src/plumbing/oauth/authorizer.ts

Comment: My Java version is v similar, bit a bit more complex and not documented yet: https://github.com/authguidance-examples/authguidance.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/api/basicapi/framework/security/OAuthAuthorizer.java

Comment: Thank for the links, @Gary Archer!

Answer (score 0):

Meant to say: your user registration page should save data to 2 different sources - it is tricky - but worth taking the time to get right ..